# printling all probable outcomes c++?

Tags: c++, loops, multidimensional-array, permutation

Hello i am trying to figure out how to write a code so that it loops and >prints all possible outcomes for example if we start off with an array.

```
string alphabet[2][4] = { {"A","D","G","J"},
                          {"B","E","H","K"}};
```

Now i need a set of loops that will print out all different possible outcomes
using every element which should come out to be 16 possible outcomes.

the example outcomes would be:

```
ADGJ
ADGK
ADHJ
ADHK
etc....
```

Comment: Are you required to use loops?  Or allowed to use the best tool for the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for combinations.

You can use a recursive generator like, for example:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39296e24d39c2c18)</kbd>**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename F>
void combis(char const* a, char const* b, F f, std::string state = "") {
    if (a && b && *a && *b) {
        combis(a+1, b+1, f, state + *a);
        combis(a+1, b+1, f, state + *b);
    } else
    {
        f(state);
    }
}

int main() {
    combis("ADGJ", "BEHK", [](auto s) { std::cout << "Found: '" << s << "'\n"; });
}
```

Prints

```
Found: 'ADGJ'
Found: 'ADGK'
Found: 'ADHJ'
Found: 'ADHK'
Found: 'AEGJ'
Found: 'AEGK'
Found: 'AEHJ'
Found: 'AEHK'
Found: 'BDGJ'
Found: 'BDGK'
Found: 'BDHJ'
Found: 'BDHK'
Found: 'BEGJ'
Found: 'BEGK'
Found: 'BEHJ'
Found: 'BEHK'
```

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case when generating combinations and permutations, this can be viewed (and solved) as a simple matter of counting.

In this case, you have two possibilities at each of four positions. In short, what you really have is a 4-digit binary number, with some rather strange "digits". That being the case, we can simply count from 0 to 15, and use bits of that number as an index to select the correct "digit" to display in the output.

Code to do that could look something like this:

```
char output[][2] = { { 'A', 'B'}, {'D', 'E'}, { 'G', 'H'}, {'J', 'K'} };

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        std::cout << output[j][(i>>(3-j)) & 1];
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Although it's clearly not (even close to) the only way to do the job, and perhaps not even the most obvious, I think it's at least somewhat simpler than most of the alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

If you are allowed to use features of the STL, the [std::next_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) function will do exactly what you are looking for:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> alphabet = { {"A","D","G","J"},
                                                   {"B","E","H","K"}};

for(auto& v : alphabet) {
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    do {
        for(const auto& c : v) {
            std::cout << c << std::endl;
        }
    } while(std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```